# How to change pivot point for rotation on TrackballControls but keep camera.lookAt position same?

Tags: three.js

I need to be able to change rotation pivot without changing camera lookAt on THREE.TrackballControls no mater what I tried I could not succeed. Please give me a direction to solve this problem. What I am actually trying to achieve is Revit like mouse controls.

Comment: It it not doable through current version of THREE.TrackballControls API (r78). I suggest modifying this module or writing another one. Module stores initial target position in `moduleContext.target0` variable. So the hack to get in could be changing the row `_this.object.lookAt(_this.target);` to `_this.object.lookAt(_this.target0);` in `trackballControls.update` function and modifying `trackballControls.panCamera` function.

Comment: mlkn: I know simply changing target property won't do the trick. I am trying to modify the code and add "pivot" property where target property defines the lookat direction and pivot property defines the rotation pivot point and they don't have to be the same points as I described above

Comment: mlkn: The code requires much more modification than that. Current TrackballControls describes the camera as a target point with a camera arm (_eye vector). Imagine it as a selfie stick where your hand is the target and the stick is the _eye vector. the camera always looks at your hand and the _eye vector is modified upon rotation, zoom or pan...

Comment: Once I have something that I can show, I will put it here on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by creating 2 3D objects named orbit and target, then add target and camera into orbit as child objects... camera always looks at target.position, mousemove on x axis rotates the orbit object around Z axis (hence target and camera rotates around the orbit) and mousemove on y axis rotates the camera arm (camera.position vector) around cameraSideways direction.