# How to move and object but keep the child object in the same (world) location

Tags: three.js

I am trying to find the solution to the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906023/how-to-change-pivot-point-for-rotation-on-trackballcontrols-but-keep-camera-look). I think I achieved the solution by creating and orbit object and inserting the camera as a child object to this one.

I want to be able to move the orbit object but keep the camera in the same world location. I tried this;

```
this.orbit.position.add(travel);
this.camera.position.sub(travel);
```

This works perfectly until I do rotation. The fact that my orbit object will have rotation about Z (only Z) axis is making things (world to local conversions) hard for me. and the code above obviously moves my camera to wrong locations.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to see that you solved it, but I thought this might also be interesting for you in the event that things get more crazy -

I saw something in the SceneUtils that might be relevant - [the attach/detach function](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras/SceneUtils). So you could do something like detach them, do whatever parent independent things you plan to do, then reattach them. This is nice because you can still do parent-y stuff between them, but you can also create blocks where they move in world space, and then reattach without the child moving to worldCoordinates in between.

Comment: That was what I looked for in the first place. A function that detached the child objects while preserving it's global position/rotation but I could not find it. So here it is... Thanks. Although I already solved my problem I accept this as a real answer for the help and as a welcome to you...

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to transform the travel vector by using quartenion of the orbit object:

```
this.orbit.position.add(travel);    
this.camera.position.sub(travel.applyQuaternion(this.orbit.quaternion));
```

it did not work...

Since I wasn't sure what quarternions are exactly doing and rotation of orbit is only around Z axis it was quite easy to transform the travel vector to local coordinates as follows:

```
            this.orbit.position.add(t);

            var angle = -this.orbit.rotation.z;
            var x = t.x * Math.cos(angle) - t.y * Math.sin(angle);
            var y = t.x * Math.sin(angle) + t.y * Math.cos(angle);

            var t2 = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, t.z);

            this.target.position.sub(t2);
```

And it works like a charm...